# Spring Boot and Maven - bundling two apps into one fat jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have built two Spring Boot apps - secured Rest layers for some other web layer. My goal is to have these two as below Maven setup:

```
 system (mvn main module)
    commons (mvn submodule)
    ...
    rest (mvn submodule orchestrating its submodules: rest1 and rest2 and bundling them into one spring boot)
       rest1 (mvn submodule - spring boot)
       rest2 (mvn submodule - spring boot)
    ...
```

So I can decide if I take rest1 and rest2 combined into one Spring Boot fat jar or just one of them, and run.

I have reasons to have these two rest bundled into one Spring Boot...
Both should also be exposed as :8080/(context)/rest1/... and 8080/(context)/rest2/...

Is it possible to set up the above in some clean way with Maven? (I assume that some of the code should now be shared and put into the rest module, right?)

Comment: If a proxy would be fine for you it might be a cleaner solution, since you do not require heavy customizing. You can just stay with two regular Spring Boot apps, which you can run and maintain independently on a server (on two different ports). Using a proxy (such as HAProxy) will allow you to add the context paths. To stay with Spring you could even leverage Spring Cloud with Eureka Service Discovery and Zuul as a Gateway.

Comment: Spring Cloud is really great but it would be quite a big step considering my current setup... BTW: How does the security come into the play with Eureka and Zuul? Would it be possible to use shared layer for this? RE my question I will end up with one Spring Boot app just built from submodules...

Comment: Security can quite easy be achieved using shared tokens, for example from an OAuth2 Auth Server.
RE your original question: it might be possible to write a third ("parent") Spring Boot App that uses `@ComponentScan` to import the components of the two child-applications. Not sure if something can go wrong with three main methods in there.